# C# WPF MVVM localization

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

I decided to add localization to C# WPF MVVM, after searching the Internet I found several options how to do it, but none of them works in my case because the File Resource does not exist after I name it lang.en-us.resx.

[image: this is my resx]

This is the code for UserControl

```
xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:tSeracherr.WPF.Languages">

<TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:Lang.Home}"
           FontSize="28"
           Width="120"
           TextAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Margin="5"                  
           Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockInListBox}"/>
```

I tried this method of changing the language, but it doesn't work

```
public ICommand UkrLang
{
    get
    {
            return ChangeLanguage("uk-uk");
    }
}

private ICommand ChangeLanguage(string langCode)
{
    return new DelegateCommand(obj =>
    {
        var culture = new CultureInfo(langCode);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
        Process.Start(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    });
}
```

I also tried this method, but I don't know how to finish it correctly because none of my options worked.

```
public ICommand UkrLang
{
    get
    {
        return ChangeLanguage("uk-uk");
    }
}
private ICommand ChangeLanguage(string langCode)
{
    return new DelegateCommand(obj =>
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.LanguageCode = langCode;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

        // dont now

        Process.Start(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show more code and errors.

Comment: When you set the `CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` then it is set in the context of the current process and not the next process you start and expect to have that language set.

Comment: @SirRufo I understand, but then how can I change the language without restarting the application?

Comment: Or how to persist the culture information ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to persist the selection of the language/culture to survice the restart of the application.

There is an appliction settings right build in, you only have to use them.

[image]

And when you start the application you first read that setting and set the culture.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var cultureName = WpfApp.Properties.Settings.Default.CultureName;

        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( cultureName ) )
        {
            var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( cultureName );
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        }
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof( FrameworkElement ),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( XmlLanguage.GetLanguage( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag ) ) );
    }
}
```

The command code should now look like

```
private ICommand ChangeLanguage(string langCode)
{
    return new DelegateCommand(obj =>
    {
        // write to application settings
        // that path may be different in your app
        WpfApp.Properties.Settings.Default.CultureName = langcode;
        WpfApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Process.Start(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    });
}
```

**BTW** According to the [Country Language List](https://www.fincher.org/Utilities/CountryLanguageList.shtml) there are known language code `uk-UA` (and as main `uk`). `uk-uk` is unknown.

The first two letters are for the language and the last two letters are for the country.

The german language `de` f.i. is spoken in Germany `de-DE`, in Austria `de-AT` and Switzerland `de-CH`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks cool but still doesn't work. The app restarts and saves the country code in Settings, but it seems to not find the resource file with the appropriate code.

Comment: Did you read the info after **BTW**? `uk-uk` is unknown (=> invalid) and you cannot use that. Rename your file to `Resources.uk.resx` and now it will work. You can still use that `uk-uk` for setting the culture info. The resource loader is intelligent enough to make a fallback from `uk-uk` to `uk`

Comment: You may find the [ResX Resource-Manager](https://github.com/dotnet/ResXResourceManager) (VS Extension) helpful as it will prevent you from using unknown and invalid language codes

Comment: Yes I read it and I understood it and did it, but the problem is that every time I create or modify a Resource File I get a bunch of errors, but as soon as I create Resource.uk-uk.resx it recreates but does not work. At the moment when I created Resource.uk.resx it throws an error that there is no SDK, I found the answer to the question on StackOverflow and installed what I needed, but the error still persists. I have a feeling that the problem is with visual studio itself, because I'm the only one on the Internet who has this problem, hahah, it's terrible. I want to cry.

Comment: You won't believe it, but I was right, the problem was in the VS Studio version. Your solution works, thank you for your help.